# Explicit <tx:advice> with explicit <tx:attributes> needed to make JDBC outbound gateway/adapter to commit, why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.10 and supplying it some XML configuration for Spring Integration. The problem I encounter is this: in my JDBC outbound gateways and adapters I need to specify an explicit `<tx:advice>` element with an explicit `<tx:attributes>` subelement inside the `<int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>` otherwise the transaction won't be committed and changes will be lost.

As an example:

```xml
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="myAdapter"
    channel="inputChannel"
    data-source="dataSource"
    query="UPDATE `MyTable` SET `param1` = :param1, `param2` = :param2 WHERE `id` = :id"
    sql-parameter-source-factory="myParameterSourceFactory">
    <int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">
            <property name="retryTemplate"
                ref="myRetryTemplate" />
        </bean>
        <tx:advice transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <tx:attributes>
                <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>
    </int-jdbc:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

As I said, if I omit the `<tx:advice>`, or if I specify it as an empty `<tx:advice />` element (to say: use default transaction into for propagation, isolation, etc. for all method calls), the transaction is not committed and nothing gets written to the database, even if queries are indeed executed.

By debugging I see that `txInfo` in `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionInfo)` is `null`. So, what I suspect is that something is missing which should define the default transaction definition to apply when no explicit attributes are given.

In my legacy applications (not using Spring Boot, but using a Spring Framework web application context set up mainly through XML configuration) I don't need to provide explicit `<tx:advice>` elements and:

- if I don't specify anything, my JDBC outbound gateways/adapters do commit the transaction
- if I define a poller inside an inbound adapter and I want it to open a transaction, I just need to specify an empty `<tx:advice>` to make it open a read/write transaction with a `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` propagation and so on

After all, this is what [the Spring Framework documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-txadvice-settings) says. I suspect Spring Boot auto configuration mechanism is skipping some initialisation required when using XML configuration, but I couldn't find out what.

Comment: So, to summarize: if you don't specify `<tx:advice>` it works well. And I know why: the local transaction in DB i started and closed. But if you have `<tx:advice>`, then you have to also add `<tx:method>`. The `transaction-manager="transactionManager"` does not make sense, since this is exactly the name it looks for from context. Please, consider to share a simple project with us so we can reproduce on our side.

Comment: Not really. If I don't specify `<tx:advice>`, reading works ok, but nothing gets written to the database. To be more precise: an outbound adapter writes nothing (although it performs the query), while an outbound gateway executes the UPDATE (but writes nothing) followed by the SELECT (which hence can't read updated data). To summarize: I must specify `<tx:advice>` and I must specify the `<tx:attributes>`. In any other case, the transaction is not committed and nothing gets written to the database. I'll try to see if I can isolate this in a reproducible test case...